# How to distort an image to according to path with four points in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

How do I distort an image to fit a shape? The edges of the images should fit within the edges of SVG shape.

I have been using CSS 3D transform. Are there any alternatives? Using 3D transforms let us transform for a specific shape. For example, if I create three SVG templates of an iPhone 6, then I would like images to fit on each of those automatically to the screen.

It seems like a solution in Javascript would be possible, but I don't know how.

### Example

[image: image distortion example]

Comment: What coding have you already done? Do you have a question about your code?

Comment: You'd need to apply a CSS 3D transform to the shape.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. I have been using 3D transform but I wanted to know if there are alternatives. Using 3d Transforms let us transform for a specific shape. For example if I create three SVG template of an iPhone 6 then I would like images to fit on each of those automatically to the screen. I think it can be done using JS, but just do not know how

Comment: There are no other alternatives. Only a 3d transform will let you do a non-affine transform.

Comment: I pulled up the info from the above comments into the question. Your image was great, but there wasn't enough detail in the original question regarding what you were really getting at.

Comment: @Barett, the exact thing would be, when we want to fit an image inside a a mobile frame template that in orthographic or perspective view,we use some 3dtransformation, usually matrix3d. I was thinking we can use rect in SVG to fit image in it so that the four points of borders of image fit in rect with given id using JS without transforming the image manually.